# Sell app for specific language in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

How can I offer my app on google play for only specific languages.  ( Not for specific countries ). Example . I would like to only allow french speakers to download my app. But french people can live also outside of france. So I need a country independent filter.

Comment: People can change their language at any time on their phone. I don't suggest this and I don't see a reason for it.

Comment: My app detects the language setting of the device and downloads content in that language. My app is ready for only one language (French) at the moment and I like to prevent users from other languages to pay the app . ( I get claims ). But of course there are french-peoples outside of france. Myself ( who likes to test my app, final production test at least ) for example can't see my app in google play because I am in a country ( Enlgand) which I prevent but speak the content language (French).

Comment: You can't tell what language they're on until after the app is downloaded. On your Developer Console, you can restrict the area in the world that people can download it from, but that's probably all. Just restrict them to France until you can later make it public to everyone.

Comment: Yes you are right. I guess this is the only way doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption you have to make is that french speakers will have their phones localized for France/french or another french(Canadian french). Localize your app for french only. If the user has their phone set to english or some other language, they want to use apps and services in english.